# No output from new API - GoogleNews

Tags: python, api

Trying to run the following code from a new API called GoogleNews, but no text output is created.

```
from GoogleNews import GoogleNews
googlenews = GoogleNews()

googlenews.search('Corona')

print(googlenews.result())
```

The googlenews.result() is supposed to return a list in this format: [{'title': '...', 'media': '...', 'date': '...', 'desc': "...", 'link': '...', 'img': '...'}]

When executed the only result is: "Finished in 0.057".

There are other functions such as "googlenews.gettext()" which should only bring the news articles names but have the same issue there.

Any ideas why this isn't working? Does it need to be printed out in some special way or what do you guys think?

Br,
Olle

Comment: Also, here is the site for the API: https://pypi.org/project/GoogleNews/

Comment: How are you running this your code? Your code works OK as-is, it *does* return an array of search results and are printed out, whether if I run it from a terminal or [from my IDE (VS Code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCRHQ.png). I think you are also using an IDE, but maybe you are just not looking at the correct panel / console output..?

Comment: Have you tried running it directly from the command line or from Python shell?

Comment: Well, I'm using Atom and when running a good old: print("hello world.") it gets shown in the output down at the bottom.

Comment: The same result when running the python script from the terminal, it just shows "[]". Nothing else.

Comment: From the [code](https://github.com/HurinHu/GoogleNews/blob/master/build/lib/GoogleNews/googlenews.py#L3), it seems to rely on BeautifulSoup to scrape the Google search page. If the format changes, or if your network/IP blocks the search, or if Google blocks your IP, then you won't get any results. I suggest [reporting it to the developer](https://github.com/HurinHu/GoogleNews/issues). Similar people have reported the same issue.